# How to make aux type compile?

Tags: scala, types

I have the following example with aux type, that does not compile:

```
trait Foo[A] {

  type B

  def value: B

}

object Foo {

  type Aux[A0, B0] = Foo[A0] { type B = B0}
 implicit def footInt = new Foo[Int] {
   override type B = String

   override def value = "Hey!"
 }

  implicit def fooString = new Foo[String] {
    override type B = Boolean

    override def value = true
  }

}


import cats._
import cats.implicits._

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val x: Id[String] = "Hello"

    println(foo(1))
    println(foo("Hello"))

    println(fooAux(1)(x))

  }

  def foo[T](t: T)(implicit f: Foo[T]): f.B = f.value

  def fooAux[T, R] (t: T) (implicit f: Foo.Aux[T, R], id: Id[R]) : R = f.value

}
```

the compile complains:

```
Error:(15, 22) not enough arguments for method fooAux: (implicit f: com.sweetsoft.Foo.Aux[Int,R], implicit id: cats.Id[R])R.
Unspecified value parameter id.
    println(fooAux(1)(x))
Error:(21, 55) parameter value id in method fooAux is never used
  def fooAux[T, R] (t: T) (implicit f: Foo.Aux[T, R], id: Id[R]) : R = f.value
Error:(4, 23) Unused import
import cats.implicits._
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are all the `cats` imports doing in this code, and why do you have repeatedly `Id[T]` instead of just `T`? Please get rid of the unnecessary dependencies, this is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It compiles with minor modifications:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  type B
  def value: B
}

object Foo {

  type Aux[A0, B0] = Foo[A0] { type B = B0 }

  implicit val footInt = new Foo[Int] {
    override type B = String
    override def value = "Hey!"
  }

  implicit def fooString = new Foo[String] {
    override type B = Boolean
    override def value = true
  }

}

object App {

  type Id[X] = X

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val x: Id[String] = "Hello"
    println(foo(1))
    println(foo("Hello"))
    println(fooAux(1))

  }

  def foo[T](t: T)(implicit f: Foo[T]): f.B = f.value

  def fooAux[T, R] (t: T) (implicit f: Foo.Aux[T, R], id: Id[R]): R = id

}
```

The first error is pretty clear: the second argument list of `fooAux` needs two arguments, but you pass just a single `x`.

The second error message is also quite mundane: you don't ever use `id`.

The rest works almost as-is as soon as you provide an implicit `String` (I assume that you wanted to make `x` implicit).